# Add a right click context menu in certain WIndows folders that will open a web browser URL?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

In a Windows Explorer window where you browse files in Windows 7, I would like to add a new context menu that will allow me to open a file on my local Dev Server.

So it would have to open a browser like Google Crome and the URL would have to be the file path but slightly different removing part of it and prepending my localhost URL.

For example if the file I am right clicking on, the path for that file might be...

`E:\Server\htdocs\labs\php\testProject\test.php`

I would need a button to click in the context menu `Open in Browser` and it would open my Web Browser with a URL like this...

`http://localhost/labs/php/testProject/test.php`

I would love to be able to do this, any ideas or help would greatly be appreciated!

To go one step further, would to be able to somehow make the context menu item only show up on File that are under this folder.... ``E:\Server\htdocs` but this is far less important.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Add, Remove, Edit Context Menu items in Windows 7 | 8](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors). It lists  different context menu editors:

- Ultimate Windows Customizer
- Right-Click Extender for Windows
- Context Menu Editor for Windows
- ContextEdit will allow you easily control the items that appear on your context menu of Windows Explorer
- ShellExtView or  ShellMenuView. They are small utilities that display the list of static menu items that appear in the context menu when you right-click a file/folder in Windows Explorer, and allow you to easily disable or edit unwanted menu items.
- File Menu Tools lets you add, delete & customize the context menu items of the Windows Explorer.
- for a fast and easy way to clean up your Window Explorer and Internet Explorer right-click context menu, try MenuMaid.

Links are provided for all of these together with addition information and screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much know how to add the custom context menus, that is the easy part and is everywhere on the web, I can make a context menu that opens a Windows .bat file.

The .bat file that does all the work is where the hard part was and I now have that solution from another question I had asked.  The code for the .bat file is below...

```
@echo off
set input=%1
Echo.Input was - %input%
set converted=%input:E:\server\htdocs\=http://localhost/%
set converted=%converted:\=/%
echo.Converted to - %converted%

start "webpage name" %converted%
```

will update later with the steps to add the context menu that runs this bat file as well